# Google maps zoom range

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, range, zooming

I am on a small problem concerning the zoom of a google maps.
I want to make a bar range with my "own zoom" here is what it looks like and here is my code. 
[image]

My code:

```js
handleValuesChange(component, values) {
    this.setState({
      values: values,
    });
    if(values === 500){
      this.setState({nbLatLn: 0.004})
    }
    if(values === 1000){
      this.setState({nbLatLn: 0.008})
    }
    if(values === 1500){
      this.setState({nbLatLn: 0.012})
    }
    if(values === 2000){
      this.setState({nbLatLn: 0.016})
    }
    if(values === 2500){
      this.setState({nbLatLn: 0.020})
    }
    if(values === 3000){
      this.setState({nbLatLn: 0.024})
    }
    if(values === 3500){
      this.setState({nbLatLn: 0.028})
    }
    if(values === 4000){
      this.setState({nbLatLn: 0.032})
    }
    if(values === 4500){
      this.setState({nbLatLn: 0.036})
    }
    if(values === 5000){
      this.setState({nbLatLn: 0.04})

    }
  }
  
  
  /////////////////
  
  
  
  <Segment textAlign='center'>
                  <Container className="TailleRange">
                    <InputRange 
                      maxValue={5000}
                      minValue={500}
                      formatLabel={values => `${values}m`}
                      step={500}
                      value={this.state.values}
                      onChange={this.handleValuesChange.bind(this)}/>
                  </Container>
</Segment>
```

But it does not work, do you want to find the little problem?
I continue my research! :)

Comment: What exactly does not work? That shared code does not look like valid JS or HTML code

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your answer. I just want to be able to zoom in and out with this bar on a map

Comment: How do you use this code to your Google Maps code? do you use the `nbLatLn` as your zoom level?

Comment: There must be more code for the connection to Google Maps....

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unclear and the markup was peculiar to say the least with no obvious signs of how the javascript code given ties in with Google Maps but perhaps the following might be of use.

The function you had could, looking at it quickly, be simplified quite a lot as depicted below.

```
<div class='slidecontainer'>
  <input type='range' min='500' max='5000' value='2250' step=500 class='slider' id='zoom-slider' />
</div>

<script>
    var slider=document.getElementById('zoom-slider');

    var handleValuesChange=function( event ){
        /* every step of 500 increases nbLatLn by this amount */
        var i=0.004;

        /* emulate callback method `this.setState()` */
        var setState=function( v ){
            return { nbLatLn: v };
        }
        /* calculate the value to set */
        var n=( ( this.value / 500 ) * i ).toPrecision(2);

        /* return object */
        return setState( n );
    }



    /* one of the ways you could call the function */
    slider.onchange=function(event){

        /* use this value somewhere, somehow to change map zoom */
        var state=handleValuesChange.bind( this ).call( this, event );

        /* do something with returned Object */
        console.log( state )
    }.bind( slider );
</script>
```

Alternatively it would be far simpler to tie the slider directly into the map method `setZoom` ( change apikey to run as demo )

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script async defer src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=<APIKEY>&callback=initMap"></script>
        <script>
            var map;

            function initMap(){
                var options = {
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.478595, -1.889729),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), options );

                var slider=document.getElementById('zoom-slider');
                var span=document.getElementById('zoom');
                    span.innerHTML=map.getZoom();


                slider.onchange=function(e){
                    var zoom=parseInt( this.value ) / 250;
                    map.setZoom( zoom );
                    span.innerHTML=zoom;
                }.bind( slider );
            }

        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #map {
                width: 100%;
                height: 80vh;
                margin-top: 10px;
            }
            .container {
                width: 50%;
                float:none;
                margin:1rem auto;
            }
            .slider {
                -webkit-appearance: none;
                width: 100%;
                height: 5px;
                border-radius: 5px;   
                background: #d3d3d3;
                outline: none;
                opacity: 0.7;
                -webkit-transition: .2s;
                transition: opacity .2s;
            }
            .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
                -webkit-appearance: none;
                appearance: none;
                width: 15px;
                height: 15px;
                border-radius: 50%; 
                background: red;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
                width: 15px;
                height: 15px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                background: red;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            #zoom{
                display:block;
                width:2rem;
                padding:1rem;
                box-sizing:border-box;
                clear:none;
                margin:1rem auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id='map'></div>
    <div class='container'><span id='zoom'></span>
      <input type='range' min='250' max='5000' value='2500' step=250 class='slider' id='zoom-slider' />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes excuse me I was not precise enough here is the rest of my code

```
createMap() {
  this.state.map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: this.state.lat, lng: this.state.long},
    zoom: this.state.zoom
  });
let southWest = new window.google.maps.LatLng(this.state.lat-0.016,this.state.long-0.016);
let northEast = new window.google.maps.LatLng(this.state.lat+0.016,this.state.long+0.016);
let bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds(southWest,northEast);
this.state.map.fitBounds(bounds);
  new window.google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: this.state.lat, lng: this.state.long},
    map:  this.state.map
  });
  this.state.Parking.map((element) => {
    let marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: element.latitude, lng: element.longitude},
      icon: POI,
      map:  this.state.map
    });
    let contentString = '<div class="InfoWindow" ' + '<h2>' + element.title + '</h2>' + '<p>' + element.number + element.street + '<br/>'+
      element.postcode + element.city + '</p>' + '<p>'+'10min  1.2km' + '</p>'+ '</div>';
    if (marker && contentString) {
      this.addInfoWindowToMarker( this.state.map, marker, contentString, element.idPark)
    }
  });
```

}